# Why isn't my drop down menu working in IE?

Tags: html, css

I've created a drop down menu which works fine in Opera, FF, Chrome and Safari.
But of cours it's not working in IE 8.

You can see the menu here: http://sanabygg.stiengenterprises.com - menu item `Systemgulv`.

Can any one tell me why this is not working here?

You can see a sandbox of the solution ehre: http://jsfiddle.net/bCJKd/2/

From what I can see, it's not a `z-index` issue.

This is the CSS I'm using:

```
#mainmenu
{
  display: block;
  line-height: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: Cuprum, Georgia, Times, Arial, serif;  
  float: right;
  padding-top: 43px;
  position: relative;
  z-index:auto;
}

/* Sub navigation */
#menu-main-menu ul.sub-menu {
  position: absolute;
  z-index:999;
  min-width: 130px;
  visibility:hidden;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 0.80em;
  padding: 5px; 
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);  /* FF3+, Saf3+, Opera 10.10+, Chrome, IE9 */
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#99000000, endColorstr=#99000000)";
  -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
     -moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
          box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);

}

#menu-main-menu li:hover ul, #menu-main-menu li li:hover ul, 
#menu-main-menu li li li:hover ul, #menu-main-menu li.sfhover ul, 
#menu-main-menu li li.sfhover ul, #menu-main-menu li li li.sfhover ul {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

Comment: @Justin The DOCTYPE says otherwise - altough I might now have used all the tags one can use in HTML5.

Answer (score 0):

Set the z-index property of the parent div, to auto. If you do not set the position and z-index property in IE, for all parent divs, the z-index of the child div is ignored. Hope you get my point.

If you have multiple position:relative elements in your code, then IE sets up separate Z layer contexts for each one, which ignore each other.

Comment: @anirudh4444 - I've set the `z-index` of the mainmenu to `auto` and the submenu to `999`. But still no change :( (see updated css above)

Comment: Do you know the URL to the sandbox where I can put code and share? I forgot the name of the site.

Comment: From the above solution, one other thing comes to mind... IE operates in quirks mode when you get the <!doctype> wrong...

Comment: @anirudh4444 - That's the one. I'ev added code here, and from what I can see, the problem isn't z-index. http://jsfiddle.net/bCJKd/2/

Comment: The doctype is standard HTML5 `<!DOCTYPE html>`, so it should not go into quirk mode.

Comment: PS. Another site I've used the same technique is this one: http://www.advicis.no/ - and it's working here. Going to look into that later.

Comment: Your dropdown at http://sanabygg.stiengenterprises.com/, is working for me in IE8...

Comment: U sure you are not being served some cached copy of the page?

Comment: Yep. I've had some friends test using IE8 as well. Will look more at this on Sunday.

Answer (score 0):

What @Cthulhu said and it will be worthwhile checking the dimensions of the item you want to hover over because it will be different in IE than in the other browsers.